# Numerical optimization with Scipy: Practical recommendations

Tags: python, scipy, simulation, mathematical-optimization

I was trying to learn Scipy, using it for simulation-based optimization. The objective function is evaluated based on a simulation model without having any information about derivatives. Constraint violations are penalized by adding penalty terms. During the last years I worked more on simulation and my optimization knowledge is based on some classes and so I am lacking of "practical knoweledge". I also searched for some practical guidelines using scipy - but I could not find anything relevant. I want to test several algorithms from`scipy.optimize.minimize` like Nelder-Mead or TNC or `scipy.optimize.differential_evolution`. I list some fundamental questions that arose during the last week of trying to get into this topic:

- Value (range) of the optimization function: Should the value  be in the magnitude of 1? I work on an example where I try to minimize an input trajectory (the objective function is to minimize the integral). If I don't scale it down, the  value is in the magnitude 1e7. In what magnitude should the penalty term be? How would you increase the penalty term in each iteration?
- This question is related to the previous: I guess some settings depend on the magnitude of the value of the objective function: *Tolerance for termination*, *step size used for numerical approximation of the jacobian*, *Maximum step for the line search* or *xtol/xatol* and *ftol/fatol*. Are there some practical recommendations?

Would be great if someone could help me, or link to practical examples/literature.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers. As I see it, your post lacks a question or is not clear what you desire. Could you edit it to correct so?

Comment: I work on similar things - hope this adoption is OK